# Active Model Serializer not rendering the root key for collection - Version- 0.10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I am using `'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.6'` for rendering my API response. For my `index` action I am doing this -

```
render json: @items, root: 'data', each_serializer: ItemsSerializer
```

but in my response, I am not getting the `root key` - `data`

```
[
  {
    "id": 85,
    "title": "B",
    "source": "manager_added",
    "shared": true,
    "status": "suggested",
    "item_type": "action_item",
    "manager": {
        "id": 2614,
        "full_name": "Calvin H",
        "first_name": "Calvin"
    },
    "reportee": {
        "id": 2614,
        "full_name": "Calvin H",
        "first_name": "Calvin"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 87,
    "title": "D",
    "source": "manager_added",
    "shared": true,
    "status": "suggested",
    "item_type": "action_item",
    "manager": {
        "id": 2614,
        "full_name": "Calvin H",
        "first_name": "Calvin"
    },
    "reportee": {
        "id": 2614,
        "full_name": "Calvin H",
        "first_name": "Calvin"
    }
  }
]
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hardest part with AMS is finding it's right documentation. Based on the version you have mentioned, here's the documentation link:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable/docs

There are 3 adapters:

1. `:default` (There won't be any root, basically `root` key is useless, even if you add it)
2. `:json` (This is what you need, you can add custom `root` key. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#example-output-1)
3. `:json_api` (Default `root` key will be `data`, but you can customize, maybe you can use this, but it will change the whole structure of your response json into something like: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#example-output-2)

Answer:

```
render json: @items, root: 'data', adapter: :json, each_serializer: ItemsSerializer
```

or

```
render json: @items, adapter: :json, each_serializer: ItemsSerializer
```